# Where is the best place to put this logic in an MVC design?

Tags: model-view-controller

I was considering having a ReadOnly property on the ViewModel class which returns a formatted string showing a date range that is derived from two Date properties in the same class.

Does that logic best belong in the Controller or the View Model?

If the best place is the controller, then I would only need one read/write property in the ViewModel, DateRangeForDisplay. If it was OK to put it in the ViewModel, I would have 2 date properties and the string readonly DateRangeForDisplay property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably strongly opinion based, but:

Controllers shouldn't have data properties at all. Their job is to get events from the View/UI and propagate it over to the Model/ViewModel (Exact terms depend on the selected architectural style).

Models should not care about how the data is being represented and therefore don't have such a property, except for some performance reasons.

ViewModels kind of *decorate* Models with state and formatted data, that's why such a combined date property should be in the ViewModel.

I'd say this is especially true for asp.net (or other server app models), where the viewModels are more or less just property bags to get all the state together before returning it to the client.

[image: architecture overview]